# Will savedInstanceState always be null if the user does not explicitly modify it?

Tags: java, android

According to Android's developer pages:

> Because the onCreate() method is called whether the system is creating
>   a new instance of your activity or recreating a previous one, you must
>   check whether the state Bundle is null before you attempt to read it.
>   If it is null, then the system is creating a new instance of the
>   activity, instead of restoring a previous one that was destroyed.
>   [Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#restore-activity-ui-state-using-saved-instance-state)

From what I understand, this means a conditional `if(savedInstanceState == null)` inside `onCreate()` will only run on the first instance of Activity; If the user switches between apps or changes orientation, the system will call `onCreate()` and the above conditional will return `false` and the code inside will not be executed, as expressed by the following code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Code here will run only on the *first* time onCreate() is called
    } 

    // Code here will run every time onCreate() is called
}
```

But will the code above work as expected if `saveInstanceState` object is never explicitly modified by the user?

From the above quote, it seems that a change in orientation will modify `saveInstanceState` in some way as to have the conditional described above return `true`.

I have been looking into the topic and I find no relevant information on how the system is modifying `savedInstanceState` behind the scenes (or if it is doing that at all).

So the question is:  Will `savedInstanceState` always be `null` if the user does not explicitly modify it?

Comment: What the user can do to modify it? onCreate are called only on creation step and the only once time it  is null is when it is creating for the first time, any other action (including switching activities, orientation changes and going background) will save the state

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos The user can do something such as `savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);` (as explained in the link provided above). If the system is modifying the object on configuration changes, where can I find more details on what, exactly, is happening?

Comment: But such putInformation code is only on save state, and the same state will be returned on onCreate, while just assigning savedInstanceState if null = new Bundle will have no effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SavedInstanceState will not be null after recreation of activity on device rotation. To check this you need just place breakpoint in your onCreate method and check the value of the savedInstanceState after device rotation. In my case I get this info:

[image]

You should check it by your-own.